A div with sub-divs by z-order(main.css) containing layers of images and text should be saved as new jsPDF()
I tried this:
<html>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="Connections/jspdf.min.js"></script>
...
<button class="ARButton" id="Neuer_Eintrag" onclick="saveDiv('Card_Frontside','<?php echo $Titel ?>')">Print a new card ?</button>
...
</html>

<script>
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [587,956]);

function saveDiv(divId, title) {
doc.fromHTML('<html><head><title>-</title><link href=\"main.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" /></head><body><div class=\"Card_Front_Page\" id=\"Card_Front_Page\">' + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML + '</div></body></html>');
doc.save(title + '.pdf');
</script>


By the first click on the button it does an empty PDF.
By the second click on the button it does all (5) layers as (5) pages in this PDF.
How can I get a PDF with one page with all (5) layers on top of each other?

@KJ there is no overflow issue. The problem is: with fromHTML(...) the css informations all get lost.

@KJ is there an alternative to fromHTML ?
